# Adding Numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Please advise how to ADD two numbers in JavaScript. I am not sure where I am going wrong here. Not clear how I need to convert string into integers or Numbers.

```js
function add(){
"use strict";
        num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstNumber")).value;
        num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondNumber")).value;

parseInt(document.getElementById("result")).innerHTML =num1+num2;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="MyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="myEvents.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>

<form>
1st Number : <input type="text" id="firstNumber" /><br>
2nd Number: <input type="text" id="secondNumber" /><br>



<input type="button" onClick="add()" Value="add" />


</form>

<p>Total: 
<div id="result"> 
<input type="text"/> </div>
```

Comment: Next time you have a question, break it down to only what is needed to reproduce the problem.  I think with some basic debugging, you would have found the answer on your own.  Use breakpoints in your code, `console.log()`, etc., to inspect values at each step of the way until you see what the issue is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to parse the *element* as an int, and take the value of the *int*:

```
parseInt(document.getElementById("firstNumber")).value
```

Get the value from the element and parse *that* as an int:

```
parseInt(document.getElementById("firstNumber").value)
```

---

Also, parsing is unnecessary here (and doesn't really make sense when assigning to the property):

```
parseInt(document.getElementById("result")).innerHTML =num1+num2;
```

Just assign the property directly:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =num1+num2;
```

Comment: Don't forget to point out everything wrong with `parseInt(document.getElementById("result")).innerHTML` too

Answer (score 4):

```
parseInt(document.getElementById("result")).innerHTML = num1 + num2;
```

This makes no sense. I’ll try to give an overview of the objects and functions you’re working with, because one or more of them seems to be being treated as a sort of magic.

Starting with elements:

```
var firstInput = document.getElementById("firstNumber");
var secondInput = document.getElementById("secondNumber");
```

`document.getElementById` is a function that takes a string, finds the element in your document with that id, and returns that *element*. Here, you’ve selected two `<input>` elements, which the above snippet assigns to `firstInput` and `secondInput` to distinguish them (`<input>`s) from numbers.

Each input has a `value` property, which is a *string*. Verify this in your browser’s console.

```
console.log(firstInput.value);  // whatever you typed in the first box
console.log(typeof firstInput.value);  // string
```

Onwards to parsing, then. `parseInt` is a function that parses a string into a number. You can try it out in your console, too:

```
var someString = "192";
var someNumber = parseInt(someString);

console.log(someNumber);  // 192
console.log(typeof someNumber);  // number
```

A quick type recap:

- `firstInput` is an element
- `firstInput.value` is a string
- `parseInt` is a function that takes a string and returns a number

so you can use `parseInt(firstInput.value)` to get your first input’s value as a number. Writing that all out for both inputs,

```
var firstInput = document.getElementById("firstNumber");
var secondInput = document.getElementById("secondNumber");

var num1 = parseInt(firstInput.value);
var num2 = parseInt(secondInput.value);
```

Now that you have two numbers, you can add them:

```
var sum = num1 + num2;
```

Finally, to put the sum back into the result element, you just have to find that element as usual:

```
var resultElement = document.getElementById("result");
```

and assign the sum to its `innerHTML`.

```
resultElement.innerHTML = sum;
```

Recalling that `parseInt` takes a string and returns a number, now you should realize that no `parseInt` needs to be involved here. You have a number already – it’s `sum`. No string is involved.

All together with comments for easy reading, with each line performing fewer steps:

```
// Get <input> elements
var firstInput = document.getElementById("firstNumber");
var secondInput = document.getElementById("secondNumber");

// Parse the text entered in each into numbers
var num1 = parseInt(firstInput.value);
var num2 = parseInt(secondInput.value);

// Find their sum
var sum = num1 + num2;

// Get the output element
var resultElement = document.getElementById("result");

// Display the sum in the output element
resultElement.innerHTML = sum;
```

Comment: The Total textbox that holds the "result" disappears every time I click on add button. Why?

Comment: @user39531: You’re selecting the `<div>` and setting its inner HTML to a new value. The textbox is part of its inner HTML. If you want to change the value displayed in the textbox instead, give *it* the `id="result"` and use `resultElement.value = sum;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstNumber").value);
var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondNumber").value);
```

you have to define the variables and correct the parentheses

Comment: My error was closing the parseInteger parenthesis before .value. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```js
function add(){
"use strict";
        var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstNumber").value);
        //You need to define your variable before use.
        var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondNumber").value);
        console.log(document.getElementById("firstNumber"));
        //this is a DOM object
        console.log(typeof document.getElementById("firstNumber").value);
        //this is a "string"
        console.log(typeof parseInt(document.getElementById("firstNumber").value));
        console.log(typeof +document.getElementById("firstNumber").value);
        //quickly  by use '+'
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =num1+num2;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="MyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="myEvents.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>

<form>
1st Number : <input type="text" id="firstNumber" /><br>
2nd Number: <input type="text" id="secondNumber" /><br>



<input type="button" onClick="add()" Value="add" />


</form>

<p>Total: 
<div id="result"> 
<input type="text"/> </div>
```