# Adding two Var numbers together?

Tags: javascript

I assigned three cells of numbers and then I wanted to sum them together,

```
var num1, num2, num3: number;
num1 = prompt("Enter num1:");
num2 = prompt("Enter num2:");
num3 = prompt("Enter num3:");

document.write((num1 + num2 + num3));
alert((num1 + num2 + num3));
```

and if i enter 10 , 20 , 30 the out put is : 102030 ,
and its need to be 60...

Thanks for the helpers.

Comment: convert string input to number.

Comment: because ur adding string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Numbers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39682758/adding-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: nice duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39682758/adding-numbers-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `prompt()` function work with string Values,
If you want to return type number add a (+) after the (=),
Take a look at this code and understand better what I meant :

```
let testPrompt1;
let testPrompt2;
testPrompt1 = prompt("Enter test 1:"); // Enter number
testPrompt2 = + prompt("Enter test 2:"); // Enter number

document.write("Type of test 1" + typeof testPrompt1 ); // String !!
document.write("Type of test 2" + typeof testPrompt2 ); // Number !!

// Add (+) before the (=) !!!!
let num1, num2, num3;
num1 =+ prompt("Enter num1:"); // 10
num2 = + prompt("Enter num2:");// 20
num3 = + prompt("Enter num3:");// 30
document.write((num1 + num2 + num3)); // Output 60
alert((num1 + num2 + num3)); // Output 60
```

I also suggest adding a variable of the result and not printing everything in one line for a better understanding of the code.

```
let num1, num2, num3, res;
num1 = + prompt("Enter num1:");
num2 = + prompt("Enter num2:");
num3 = + prompt("Enter num3:");
res = num1 + num2 + num3;
document.write("Result : " + res); // Output 60
alert("Result : " + res); // Output 60
```

Answer (score 1):

The `prompt()` function gives you a string so you have to convert it a number.
You can do what you want this way:

```
var num1, num2, num3;
num1 = parseInt(prompt("Enter num1:"));
num2 = parseInt(prompt("Enter num2:"));
num3 = parseInt(prompt("Enter num3:"));

document.write((num1 + num2 + num3));
alert((num1 + num2 + num3));
```

If you wish to use floats instead, simply replace `parseInt` with `parseFloat`.

Comment: How i can use function prompt to use numbers/int ? there is no other way i must ust parse ?

Comment: I think that using parse is the only way to do it. The [documentation for prompt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp) doesn't mention about it either. Hope this helps, it it worked for you, please consider selecting my answer as the correct one :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you convert them from string to number:

```
alert((Number(num1 ) + Number(num2) + Number(num3));
```

Answer (score 0):

JS is treating numbers like strings now, so it concatinates them. Try cast them to int(integers) so they can be added.Write smth like:

`document.write(Number(num1) + Number(num2) + Number(num3)))
alert(Number(num1)+Number(num2)+Number(num3))`